# Removing Ubuntu completely on the same partition where my Windows is also installed

Tags: wubi

I installed Ubuntu on the same partition with my windows & now both are inside drive C. I've already uninstalled it from the control panel but Ubuntu still showing when booting. Is there a way to remove the Ubuntu without re-install my windows?

Comment: Did you installed Ubuntu via wubi?If yes, then repair your windows bootloader.

Comment: Hi & Welcome to **AU**. Could you please fire-up a command prompt on your windows PC & type `bcdedit` on it, enter.. then post the output of the command please. On a related note, please do not try anything else than the given command.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... Well, if you don't want to work hard for this Windows installation, I can't help you. If you want to work quite a bit to save it, I can, but it does involve you having to reinstall windows 7... I assume you have a lot of stuff on the windows partition. Follow these steps to create a live-usb to copy windows to another partition (if you still have your installation usb you used to install Ubuntu, skip to step :

**1.** Boot your Live-USB system

**2.** Partition the hard-drive with gparted. Make a partition at least... 120 gigs. If that is the size of your hard drive or fairly close, make it 60 gigs. Format it with FAT32 or NTFS (if your UBUNTU live-usb can handle them).

**3.** Go to the file explorer and then to the new partition. It is now mounted. Now go to the computer box. Click it.

**4.** Move the following folders to the partition you created in step **2**:

Windows

Program Files

Users

Program Files (x86) (this is only here on x64 machines. **DO NOT PANIC IF IT ISN'T HERE**)

**5.** When those are finished copying, you can insert your windows installation media and reinstall windows 7. When it's done installing, you can move everything back **EXCEPT THE PROGRAM FOLDERS. YOU WILL HAVE TO REINSTALL EVERYTHING.**
Oh, and when you have windows reinstalled, you have a **NICE PARTITION TO INSTALL UBUNTU TO! :D**
Sorry, you had to go through this... Just be careful next time.